# How To Pass Parameters In String Array Of Functions In With() Laravel

Tags: laravel

I Try To Pass Parameter To With() Function For Model:

```
Model::with(['functionA($parameters)', 'functionB'])
```

Comment: You don't. The strings in `->with()`'s array should match the name of the relationships you want to include, which shouldn't take any arguments. Is there a reason you're trying to do this? What are `functionA()` and `functionB()` in this case? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74351425/edit) to include more details, like why you think you need to do this.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this type.

```
Model::with(['functionA' => function($query) use ($parameters) {
        $query->where('some_column', $parameters);
    }, 'functionB'])->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't use 'with' for normal function, it's used for eloquent's relationships.
for your case you can proceed like this:

```
$model = new Model(); // or $model = Model::where(anyConditionYouWant)->first();
$model->functionA($parameters);
```

you can use your functions any time you want without declare them in 'with' sentence

Comment: with() can be used for providing dynamic conditions with a callback function.
you are not eager loading your data and it will create N + 1 Query